# Maximum number of counters am I allowed to make/have?

Tags: tex-core, counters

I'm currently working on generating the pentest-reports of the company I work for with tex.

I came across the *totcounter* package which I use for the overview table of the findings. there i'm adding three counters per host in a table:

```
...
\newtotcounter{1.2.3.4-high}
\newtotcounter{1.2.3.4-middle}
\newtotcounter{1.2.3.4-low}
...
```

This tex-table gets generated by a ruby script which reads a nmap-report.
so I get a lot counters...

the problem I now have is that I get an error:

```
No room for a new \counter ...
```

Is there a maximum number of counters in TeX?

Comment: Can you use e-TeX? If so, load the `etex` package to get around 32k registers (otherwise you're stuck with 256). (Note: there are some registers needed for the allocation system itself, so the total available is lower than might be implied.)

Comment: Or do the counters in ruby and simply write the results into the tex file.

Comment: etex works. thanks. cant use ruby - since i increment the counters with the findings i write in tex....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The maximum number of count registers:

- TeX: 0 to 255 (2<sup>8</sup>-1)
- e-TeX: 0 to 32767 (2<sup>15</sup>-1)
- LuaTeX: 0 to 65535 (2<sup>16</sup>-1)

**Remarks:**

- Package `etex` makes the additional count registers available for LaTeX:

  ```
  \usepackage{etex}
  ```
- In LaTeX 100 or more count registers are already allocated or reserved and not available for `\newcount`/`\newcounter`. Thus about 147 count registers are free after class `report` is loaded.

### Overview table problem

Possible solutions/workarounds:

- `\usepackage{etex}`
- If the overview table comes *after* the tables, then the maximum values can also be stored in macros without the need for `.aux` files and additional LaTeX runs. Then a limited set of counters can be reused for the different tables.
- The needed values for the overview can be written into the `.aux` file. Then they are available at the next LaTeX run.